# Why isn't the value of shared changing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to pass a variable (called shared in this case) and change it's value. I thought all arguments in python were pass by reference, so I am not sure why it's not working.

```
class a:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.block = x
    def callb(self, shared = "notright"):
        print("in a")
        print("shared before: " + shared)
        self.block.callb(self, shared)
        print("shared after: " + shared)

class b:
    def callb(self, a, shared):
        print("b was called")
        shared = "yay!"
        print("shared in b: " + shared)

new = a(b())
new.callb()
```

Comment: Yes, *values* are passed by reference in Python.  Assigning to a variable causes *that variable* to reference something else; it has no effect on the object that the variable formerly referenced.

Comment: You are changing the value of a *local* variable with the same name, not the value of the local `shared` in `a.callb`. `b.callb` is basically ignoring its second argument.

Comment: You might want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Python does not really have "variables". Variables are memory locations referenced by name. Passing a variable around allows other code to access the same memory. In python though the names are just names. The `name = expr` statement does **not** change the value stored in the memory associated with the variable `name`. It simply creates an object (the result of `expr`) and binds this object to the name `name`.

Comment: @jasonharper Perhaps you mean that *references* are passed *by value*

Comment: "I thought all arguments in python were pass by reference" No, arguments are **never passed by reference** in Python. Python uses what is sometimes called "call by assignment" or "call by sharing" (that term is less common). In the Java community, you might hear "references are passed by value".  This is the same evaluation semantics as Javascript, Ruby, Java (for objects).

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the concepts of 'local' and 'global' variables.
In Python, every variable declared inside of a loop, function, class or method, is a *local* variable (unless explicitly specified), meaning that a variable is born and dies inside that specific piece of code.

When you are receiving `shared` as an input in `b.callb`, you're simply over writing it with something else and since you're not `return`ing it anywhere, it simply dies as soon as `b.callb` has ended its course.

To get what you are looking for you could declare `shared` as a global variable (not recommended using global variables tho, as they can be tricky to manage), or simply return `shared` in `b.callb` and declaring `shared` again with the value of `b.callb` when you're calling it in `a.callb`

Something like this works:

```py
class a:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.block = x
    def callb(self, shared = "notright"):
        print("in a")
        print("shared before: " + shared)
        shared = self.block.callb(shared)
        print("shared after: " + shared)

class b:
    def callb(self, shared):
        print("b was called")
        shared = "yay!"
        print("shared in b: " + shared)
        return shared

new = a(b())
new.callb()

Output:
in a
shared before: notright
b was called
shared in b: yay!
shared after: yay!
```

(notice how `b.callb` now only takes `shared` as an argument, as passing `self` into it didn't have any practical use)

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

`shared = "yay!"`

You're changing the `shared` identifier, which is local to `b.callb`, to point to a new string. After this expression, `shared` in `b.callb` starts point to a different string than one that is pointed by the `shared` identifier in `a.callb`.

Since `string` type is immutable in Python, there would be no way for you to achieve what you want, except for using a mutable object being passed around.

An example for wrapping your data in a mutable type, so you can modify when it's passed from identifier to another would be to do:

```
class s:
    def __init__(self, shared):
        self.data = shared
    def set(self, shared):
        self.data = shared

class a:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.block = x
    def callb(self, shared = s("notright")):
        print("in a")
        print("shared before: " + shared.data)
        self.block.callb(self, shared)
        print("shared after: " + shared.data)

class b:
    def callb(self, a, shared):
        print("b was called")
        shared.set("yay!")
        print("shared in b: " + shared.data)

new = a(b())
new.callb()
```

Answer (score 0):

Twice you assigned an immutable `str` (e.g. `'yay!'`) to a local variable.

You would be happier passing around some mutable data structure, perhaps a `list` or a `dict`. Then you could could assign a new string e.g. to list element `x[0]` or to dictionary entry `y['shared']`.

You may find that http://pythontutor.com/ helps you understand what is happening:
[image: vars pointing at values]